# Como executar javascript no webview do Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho uma `Activity` com o seguinte layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".WebviewActivity"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Dentro da minha `Activity` estou abrindo uma determinada url no `webview`.
Esta url possui algum javascript.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
    Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("http://paginacomjavascript.com");
}
```

Por algum motivo o `Webview` não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por padrão no WebView o javascript vem desabilitado.

Para habilitado você precisa alterar as configurações do WebView do seguinte modo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
    Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); //<<-- Retorna configurações
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);          //<<-- Altera aqui !!!

    webView.loadUrl("http://paginacomjavascript.com");
}
```